# Copying a row from another worksheet based on user input & Pasting on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to copy the row that matches the user input ID to a cell value (column A) and paste the entire row to another worksheet.

For example, given the table to be copied from:
[image]

I'd like a pop-up box to appear when the user runs the macro, and be able to input the ID they wish to copy over to the target worksheet.

So far, I have the following code but this makes you input the row number to copy - it does not reference the ID.

```
Sub test()
    
Dim a, b
Dim pastews As Worksheet, copyws As Worksheet

Set copyws = Sheets("Previous")
Set pastews = Sheets("Today")
    
a = Application.InputBox("Enter the row number to be copied.", Type:=1)
If TypeName(a) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
b = Application.InputBox("Enter the row number to be inserted into.", Type:=1)
If TypeName(b) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
copyws.Rows(Val(a)).Copy
pastews.Rows(Val(b)).Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872753/creating-and-populating-combobox-from-vba-module) to be useful

Comment: Can you explain your structure a little more clearly? Is that truly an Excel Table? So the ID number is different than the Sheet Row #?

Comment: @pgSystemTester - edited the table. As shown, ID is different from the actual row #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. Basic match function should get you there, or using VBA.Match.

```
Sub test()
Dim a, b
Dim pastews As Worksheet, copyws As Worksheet, theRow As Long

Set copyws = Sheets("Previous")
Set pastews = Sheets("Today")
    
a = Application.InputBox("Enter the ID number to be copied.", Type:=1)

If TypeName(a) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo badID:
    theRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, copyws.Columns(1), 0)
On Error GoTo 0



b = Application.InputBox("Enter the row number to be inserted into.", Type:=1)
If TypeName(b) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
copyws.Rows(theRow).Copy
pastews.Rows(Val(b)).Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Exit Sub
badID:
MsgBox "invalid ID"

End Sub
```